# jQuery Programmatically change slider value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I currently compile a list of elements into an array, I then assign click events, or if the Element is a jQuery Slider I add a function to the `slide` property.

```
this.monthly_controls = [];
(function() {
    const controls = document.querySelectorAll('[data-calculator-amount="finance-calculator"]');
    if (controls.length <= 0)
        return fatal_error('No Borrow Amount Controls');

    for (var i = 0; controls.length > i; i++) {
        var slider = false;
        if (controls[i].dataset.calculatorAmountSlider !== undefined) 
            slider = true;

        this.monthly_controls.push({
            slider: slider,
            element: controls[i],
            minus: controls[i].getElementsByClassName('term-minus')[0],
            plus: controls[i].getElementsByClassName('term-plus')[0],
            input: controls[i].getElementsByTagName('input')[0]
        });
    }
}).call(this);
```

As you can see above, I simply set `slider` to true if the Element will be a jQuery Slider, might change this to do the check a different way but thats unrelated.

```
for(var i = 0; i < _.monthly_controls.length; i++) {
    const control = _.monthly_controls[i];
    // Add event listeners and stuff...

    if (control.slider) {
        (function ($, scope) {
            $(control.element).slider({
                range: "min",
                value: scope.borrow_value,
                min: 0,
                max: 20000,
                step: 500,
                slide: function (event, ui) {
                    adjust_partners(ui.value);
                    _.borrow_value = ui.value;
                }
            });
        })(jQuery, this);
        return;
    }

    control.plus.addEventListener('click', function() {
        const new_val = (_.borrow_value + step);

        _.borrow_value = new_val;
        adjust_partners();

    }.bind(_));
    control.minus.addEventListener('click', function() {
        const new_val = (_.borrow_value - step);

        _.borrow_value = new_val;
        adjust_partners();
    }.bind(_));
}
```

Now I either assign click events to elements within my controls, or I create a jQuery Slider.

`_` will be the scope of the plugin.

Now the issue i'm having in the below code is setting the value of the Slider when one of the other controls is used, I simply can't seem to access the Slider instance.

```
var adjust_partners = function() {
    for (var x = 0; x < _.monthly_controls.length; x++) {
        if (_.monthly_controls[x].slider) {

            (function ($, scope) {
                $(scope.monthly_controls[x].element).slider('value', scope.borrow_value);
            })(jQuery, this);

            return;
        }
        _.monthly_controls[x].input.value = _.borrow_value;
    }
}.bind(_);
```

`$(scope.monthly_controls[x].element).slider('value', scope.borrow_value);` simply does nothing, trying to do `$(scope.monthly_controls[x].element).slider('value');` just dumps out the following:
[image]

Comment: [Do not post images of code or errors!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/995714)

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue, you must access the plugin instance using the `data()` function.

```
var adjust_partners = function() {
    for (var x = 0; x < _.monthly_controls.length; x++) {

        // Change slider value
        if (_.monthly_controls[x].slider) {
            (function ($, scope, x) {
                $(scope.monthly_controls[x].element).data('uiSlider').value(scope.borrow_value);
            })(jQuery, this, x);
            return;
        }

        // Change input value
        _.monthly_controls[x].input.value = _.borrow_value;
    }
}.bind(_);
```

I did try this before be I did `data('slider')` so I just put in the wrong name -_-